# Current setup maxing CPU. Need help designing AWS architecture and MySQL Clustering via AWS RDS instances

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud, mysql-replication

My company runs a mid-sized eCommerce (30,000-50,000 unique views monthly) shopping cart using X-Cart as a back-end. We are in the processing of redesigning and upgrading our back-end software. We are having issues with our current server with CPU max out from MySQL. We have some slow queries we are working on fixing but we need to move up to a new infrastructure from our current dedicated setup. Right now we have a RHEL - AMD 2.2ghz  8 core, 31 Gig RAM setup with rackspace.

The current migration plan is to goto AWS. Right now my thoughts are to push all traffic through route 53 into AWS Load Balancer. From there run Apache & PHP on a m3.xlarge, X-Cart on m3.xlarge, MySQL on a c4.2xlarge(31 ECU, 8 core double extra processing power). I plan on using AMI images and S3 bucket to store server settings for auto scaling provisions. I will keep that setup in its own zone to auto scale if needed.

**Here is where I am confused.**

- Are there any performance benefits for creating a MySQL cluster.
- From what I understand, I can create a Master and Slaves. The Slaves
  can be tuned just for read or writing privileges and I can also have
  a standby in a different zone in case of failures or outages.
- How much of a performance upgrade should I expect to see by creating
  a read slave. Also, how does scaling come into play
- I plan on getting a high CPU instance for the database, can I scale out with smaller intances?
- Right now our hosting bill is roughly 1000, Is the way I am setting up previsions powerful enough. All will be M3.xlarge which is equivalent to 15.0 GB ram  13 ecu units    4 cores  and MySQL will have a beefer server on the CPU side 31 ECU, 8 core unless we go with a cluster setup if theres a performance benefit.

Comment: 30,000 pageviews monthly is a pageview every 41 seconds on average. That really should not be maxing out anything.

Comment: We are having spikes of 95-100 Mysql usage due to slow query and we are having trouble getting our developer to fix it correctly. SELECT xcart_products.* is the issue

Comment: If you have a lot of products, a `SELECT *` call on that table will be horribly inefficient no matter how powerful the server.

Comment: We have 600,000 products. Thank you for your assistance so far, This has been an on going battle for months. We are open to paid consulting if you are interested as well.

Comment: `SELECT *` on a 600k product table means every bit of that data - likely megabytes worth - is being transferred between your webserver and your database server for every request. You won't see significant improvements without fixing that issue.

Comment: What are other options I can relay to our developer?

Comment: Your developer's code should fetch only the necessary rows to display the page at hand. Presumably you're not showing 600k products on a single page. Have them implement pagination so something like 100 products are shown on one page.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Are there any performance benefits for creating a MySQL cluster.

Not if it is a Master/Slave configuration.

If you do a Master/Master or multi-master configuration, the performance benefit will be similar to load balancing web servers, but you'll have to account for replication network traffic if you want to maintain the integrity of your data. This is no simple task.

> From what I understand, I can create a Master and Slaves. The Slaves can be tuned just for read or writing privileges and I can also have a standby in a different zone in case of failures or outages.

You can configure as many masters and slaves as you want, depending on how much complexity you are prepared to handle.

> How much of a performance upgrade should I expect to see by creating a read slave.

It's impossible to tell without information on the amount of reads your database currently serves out.

> I plan on getting a high CPU instance for the database, can I scale out with smaller intances?

Like I mentioned, it depends on how much complexity you are willing to handle. Scaling out databases is usually the last step you would take in tuning performance.

Before you need to scale your DB, you can scale your web tier, your app tier, you can add in a memcached server to cache common database queries, you can tune the indexing of your database, and so on.

Database clustering for performance, and not redundancy, is not a common scenario in my experience.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. memcached seems like a better option for now. We are open to pay for help with the transition if you are available.

Comment: There can be big performance issues with Master/slave. Multi-master replication is nothing like web balancing (the whole point is that the DB updates are sent to every node). You will run into extreme pain if you try to run more than 2 masters in an asynchronous cluster. Using memcached to cache results has limited benefit over using the SQL cahce in MySQL - and you will have worse concurrency issues. This is not a good answer.

Comment: Depends where the memcache is. If it is on the same server as webserver, it saves network traffic, and therefore decreases time to fetch data considerably. In memcache, one can also have "more processed" results.

Comment: *"If you do a Master/Master or multi-master configuration, the performance benefit will be similar to load balancing web servers"* This is not accurate.  Multiple masters do nothing meaningful to improve performance that master/slave can't offer (and do add increased complexity), while a master with one or more replica ("slave") servers can be used to dramatically scale up read-only query capacity and performance.

Comment: Instead of nitpicking small sections of my answer, why not read the entire thing? Did I say "Yeah bro you should run heaps of masters"?

Comment: Better yet, you could even make an edit, or post your own answer!